# Class don't understand Mongoose Model using typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose

Is giving a type error, he does not understand the find inside the UserInterface, this error: **Property 'find' does not exist on type 'UserInterface'**

```
import User, { UserInterface } from '../schemas/User';

class UserController {
  public user: UserInterface;

  constructor() {
    this.user = new User();
  }

  public async index(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> {
    const users = await this.user.find();
    return res.json(users);
  }
}

export default new UserController();
```

```
export interface UserInterface extends Document {
  email?: string;
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
}

const UserSchema = new Schema(
  {
    email: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  },
);

export default model<UserInterface>('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: The methods are probably provided by `model<UserInterface>` which you import as `User`. Try changing `user: UserInterface` to `user: User`.

Comment: this error: 'User' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.ts(2749)

Comment: Try `user: typeof User`

Comment: I got it, but now it doesn't take the types of the user's fields haha.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling

```
const users = await this.user.find();
```

Try calling

```
const users = await User.find();
```

As it looks like you are trying to find all users.

Comment: I try the method, but this error occurs: Expected 'this' to be used by class async method 'index'

Comment: That sounds like an eslint/tslint fail, not an error

Comment: yes, but I would like using the 'this', if not have choice I remove of eslint